# Transkription russischer Namen. Für Чебышёв, welche Norm sollte benutzt werden?

Tags: translation

Ich bin dabei ein mathematisches Werk zu verfassen, in dem der Mathematiker Pafnuty Tschebyschov (russ. Чебышёв) zitiert wird. Nun ist mir nicht klar (und auch unserem Lektorat nicht) wie man diesen Namen richtig transkribiert.

Der Duden sagt „-ow“ am Ende, ISO R9 „-ov“.

Was ist stilistisch besser?

Answer (score 7):

Da Sprache lebendig ist, würde ich nicht unbedingt die etablierten Transkriptionen (die phonetisch nicht übereinstimmen) verwenden, sondern eine die die Phonetik der ursprünglichen Sprache möglichst treu wiedergibt, solange eine Transliteration nötig ist.
Dabei ist das wichtigste **nicht „e“ sondern „o“ auf Deutsch** für den Endvokal in Чебышёв **zu verwenden**.  In Klammern kann man  hinzufügen, dass das „ë“ fälschlicherweise (das ist ja ein Faktum)  als „e“ transkribiert wurde, wenn man unbedingt als Besserwisser:in gelten möchte. Und sonst nur beispielsweise

> Tschebyschow (oftmals  „Tschebyschew”) hat bewiesen, dass...

Dadurch wird man verstanden, ohne etwas Falsches zu schreiben.

Comment: Einzig richtige Antwort, glaube ich. Nur weil irgendwas eigentlich schon immer falsch gemacht wurde, muss man es ja nicjt fortsetzen....

Comment: Tschebyscheff heißt er auch noch.

Comment: @Janka  -ff, -w, -v Endungen sind mE irrelevant (sie klingen ja nicht unterschiedlich). Der Vokal ist das Wichtigste, und er ist ein O, wenn man keine Angst hat, das Richtige zu schreiben.

Comment: Daß man nicht die etablierten Schreibweisen verwenden sollte, sondern sich an phonetisch möglichst getreue Wiedergaben halten sollte, habe ich mir auch gedacht, als ich unlängst etwas über einen Tschordsch Woschinktn gelesen habe.

Comment: Schönes Plädoyer für die korrekte Transkription: https://www.stochastik-in-der-schule.de/sisonline/struktur/jahrgang19-99/heft2/1999-2_Haller.pdf. Die Regel, dass *ё* nach *ш* als *o* transkribiert wird, ist mindestens 50 Jahre alt (steht so in meinem Duden von 1973). Warum man so tut, als ob das neu und nicht etabliert wäre, weiß ich nicht.

Comment: Danke fürs Plädoyer, David.

Answer (score 4):

In diesem speziellen Fall denke ich, dass man sich an der etablierten Transkription dieses Namens orientieren sollte, und die lautet *Tschebyscheff*: https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Tschebyscheffsche_Ungleichung

Comment: Nach dieser [Wikipedia-Seite](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tschebyschow-Polynom) geht praktisch alles, wobei die Endung *-ow* die einzige mit dem Vokal *o* ist.

Comment: @guidot Wikipedia ist da auch nur begrenzt (bzw. gar nicht) konsequent: Das nach ihm benannte Polynom ist als *Tschebyschow-Polynom*, die Ungleichung als *Tschebyschew-Ungleichung* (usw.) gelistet. Hier von "etabliert" zu reden, erscheint mir ein bißchen gewagt. Es scheint tatsächlich so zu sein, dass neuere Publikationen eher zu *Tschebyschow* neigen.

Comment: Ich kenne ihn vor allem hiervon: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tschebyschow-Polynom und war erst sehr verwirrt, ob's der Mathematiker ist.

Comment: Gegen deinen einen Beleg kann ich gut gegenhalten: [Wiki: Pafnuti Lwowitsch Tschebyschow](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pafnuti_Lwowitsch_Tschebyschow) – [Wiki: Tschebyschow-Polynom](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tschebyschow-Polynom) – [Wiki: Satz von Tschebyschow](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomisches_Integral#Satz_von_Tschebyschow) – [Wiki: Tschebyschow-Iteration](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tschebyschow-Iteration) – [Wiki: Tschebyschow-Funktion](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tschebyschow-Funktion) ...

Comment: ... [3D_Meier: Tschebyschow Geradführung](http://www.3d-meier.de/tut17/Tschebyschow/Seite1.html) – [RiskNET: Tschebyschow-Ungleichung](https://www.risknet.de/wissen/glossar-eintrag/tschebyschow-ungleichung/) – [Spektrum.de: Pafnuti Lwowitsch Tschebyschow](https://www.spektrum.de/wissen/pafnuti-lwowitsch-tschebyschow-1821-1894/1068526) – [bettermarks: Tschebyschow, Pafnuti Lwowitsch](https://de.bettermarks.com/mathe/tschebyschow-pafnuti-lwowitsch/) – [geogebra: Tschebyschow-Lambda-Mechanismus](https://www.geogebra.org/m/ctmwb8nw) Davon gibt noch jede Menge mehr.

Answer (score 3):

Als jemand, der zwar kein Wort Russisch spricht, aber den Mathematiker und sein Werk kennt, hat mich das 'o' am Ende soweit verwirrt, dass ich dachte, es handele sich um einen anderen Mathematiker. Solange dort ein 'e' steht, ist für den mathematischen Leser klar, wer gemeint ist, egal ob am Ende ein 'v' ein 'w' oder ein 'ff' steht.

Darüber hinaus ist die genaue Transkription in der Literatur nicht eindeutig, [wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pafnuti_Lwowitsch_Tschebyschow) listet verschiedene Varianten. Welche davon man verwendet ist wahrscheinlich relativ egal und ich würde die Schreibweise empfehlen, die in den zitierten Werken verwendet wird.

In englischer Sprache wird der Name (weitgehend?) einheitlich als 'Chebyshev' transkripiert, also auch mit 'e' am Ende, so dass die Übersetzung von deutsch nach englisch mit einem 'e' im deutschen auch etwas intuitiver wird.

Comment: Das läuft in etwa auf die Antwort @JonathanScholbachs hinaus (die ich auch für die richtige halte): wenn sich eine Schreibung etabliert hat, dann sollte man die schon allein deshalb verwenden, weil dadurch das (Wieder-)Auffinden erleichtert wird. (Die deutsche) Wikipedia ist in der Beziehung eher "verhaltenskreativ", siehe etwa den Schachspieler "Teimur (Teimour) Radjabov" in Google und im Vergleich in der deutschen Wikipedia

Comment: Ich habe Russisch in der Schule lernen müssen. Ich habe nie verstanden, warum Tschebyschov ohne o geschrieben wird... ;) Und ich kenne mindestens fünf Schreibweisen, die man alle irgendwie als "gebräuchlich" bezeichnen könnte. Daher auch die Frage.

Answer (score 3):

Ich unterrichte Statistik und habe für meine Studierenden ein Skriptum über Zufallsvariable geschrieben, in dem die Tschebyschowsche Ungleichung eine wichtige Rolle bei der Herleitung des Gesetzes der großen Zahlen spielt. Dort habe ich diesen Namen, wie auch gerade eben, mit *-ow* geschrieben, habe dann aber eine Fußnote mit folgendem Text hinzugefügt:

> Pafnuti Lwowitsch Tschebyschow (Пафнутий Львович Чебышёв) (1821-1894) war ein russischer Mathematiker, der viele Beiträge zu Zahlentheorie, Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung, Funktionen, Mechanik und Ballistik publiziert hat. Sein Nachname wird nach aktuellem Standard zu Čebyšëv transliteriert und in einem deutschen Kontext zu Tschebyschow transkribiert (letzte Silbe betont). Ältere, heute nicht mehr gebräuchliche deutsche Transkriptionen sind Tschebyschef, Tschebyscheff, Tschebyschew und Tschebyschev. In englischen Text findet man oft die Schreibweise Chebyshev. Viele seiner Werke erschienen zuerst aber auf französisch, daher findet man oftmals auch in deutschen Texten die französische Transkription Tchebychef.

---

**Nachtrag** (Reaktion auf Kommentare)

1. Mit *»gebräuchlich«* ist das Schreiben neuer Texte gemeint, nicht das Lesen alter Dokumente.
2. Die Frage lautete *»Welche Norm sollte benutzt werden?«* Und die Antwort kann selbstverständlich nur sein: *»Eine geltende Norm«.*

   Die Transliteration *Čebyšëv* ist tatsächlich amtlich normiert. Es handelt sich um die Norm *ISO 9:1995,* die auch unter dem Namen *»GOST 7.79-2000 System A«* zu finden ist.

   Die Transliteration ist aber ein System, dass einzelne Buchstaben aus verschiedenen Schriftsystemen einander zuordnet, ohne dabei auf die Aussprache Rücksicht zu nehmen. Insbesondere wird der kyrillische Buchstabe »ё« (Name des Zeichens in lateinischen Buchstaben: »Jo«, Aussprache in allen Sprachen, die kyrillische Zeichen verwenden: entweder »jo« oder »o«) vermutlich aufgrund seines Aussehens im lateinischen Alphabet mit einem e mit Trema (»ë«) verknüpft.

   Nur so nebenbei: Beim kyrillische Buchstaben »е« (Name: »Je«, Aussprache: »je«, z.B. »Ельцин« → »Jelzin«) macht es durchaus Sinn, ihn in lateinischer Schrift als »e« oder »je« zu schreiben, aber das ist eben ein anderer Buchstabe, so wie im Deutschen »a« und »ä« zwei verschiedene Buchstaben mit unterschiedlicher Aussprache sind.

   Aber das alles ist eigentlich egal, denn es wurde nicht nach der *Transliteration* gefragt, sondern nach der *Transkription,* und die Frage bezog sich recht unmissverständlich auf die *deutsche* Transkription. (Die Frage wurde auf german.stackexchange.com gestellt, sie wurde in deutscher Sprache formuliert und in der Frage wurde der Duden erwähnt.)

   Für die deutsche Transkription gab es in der Vergangenheit mehrere mehr oder weniger verbindliche Regelungen, die heute alle aus gutem Grund nicht mehr gelten. Einer dieser Gründe ist genau das kyrillische Jo, das immer als »e« geschrieben wurde und daher in allen Wörtern, in denen es dann in deutschen Texten vorkam, eine falsche Aussprache induzierte. Es gibt heute ja kaum jemanden im deutschen Sprachraum, der den Namen Tschebyschow richtig (nämlich mit o als letztem Vokal) ausspricht, und die Ursache dafür waren diese alten fehlerhaften Transkriptionsregeln.

   Gegenwärtig wird die Quasi-Norm des Duden-Verlags als die beste Regelung angesehen. Sie lautet für den Buchstaben Ё/ё wie folgt:

   > Nach russischen Vokalen, am Wortanfang, nach den meisten Konsonanten und nach ь sowie ъ wird ё mit 'jo' bzw. 'Jo' transkribiert; nur nach ж (sch/sh), ч (tsch), ш (sch), und щ (schtsch/stsch) jedoch mit 'o'. Beispiel: "Горбачёв" -> "Gorbatschow"

   Und obwohl es sich dabei um keine amtliche Norm handelt, ist sie gegenwärtig die sinnvollste Regelung, um russische, ukrainische und belarussische Wörter und Eigennamen in deutschen Texten mit lateinischen Buchstaben wiederzugeben.

Comment: Mit der Aussage 'heute nicht mehr gebräuchlich' wäre ich sehr vorsichtig. Das entspricht nicht meiner Erfahrung und gerade in der Mathematik kommt es häufig vor, dass auch ältere Bücher und Publikationen noch gelesen werden.

Comment: @quarague Ja, mein Bronstein, 24. Auflage 1979, "printed in the German Democratic Republic", sagt Tschebyscheff,  Sonst stimmt alles in dem Buch noch. :-)

Comment: Niemand widerspricht Bronstein ungestraft :) @HalvarF Ich glaube die Jahresangabe ist falsch. Meine 23. Auflage ist von 1987. 1979 ist dort das Jahr des Copyrights für die erste Überarbeitung der Übersetzung durch die Herausgeber Grosche, V. ZIegler und D. Ziegler.

Comment: @quarague: Wie du richtig gesagt hat, werden ältere Bücher auch heute noch *gelesen.* Aber ältere Bücher werden heute doch nicht mehr *geschrieben!* Man schreibt *neue* Bücher mit *neuen* Wörtern und verwendet dabei die *neuen* Regeln. Wörter wie *Eidam* oder *Hagestolz* stehen auch heute noch in älteren Büchern und werden daher auch heute noch *gelesen.* Deswegen sind diese Wörter heute aber trotzdem nicht mehr *gebräuchlich.* Und in genau diesem Sinne sind auch *Tschebyschef, Tschebyscheff, Tschebyschew und Tschebyschev* Transkriptionen, die heute nicht mehr *gebräuchlich* sind.

Comment: Daß sich die "Gebräuchlichkeit" ändert bei jemandem, der seit über 100 Jahren tot ist, wäre mir neu. Sollte man dann bei der veralteten Schreibweise "Goethe" auch das "th" zu "t" ändern, wie man das etwa in "Athem" bei der Reform 1901 gemacht hat, ebenso die modernen Umlaute verwenden und mithin in Zukunft "Göte" schreiben?

Comment: Das war genau mein Punkt, ich würde auch bei einem neuen Buch Tschebyscheff schreiben, weil das in der Vergangenheit gebräuchlich war und es sich hier um einen Eigennamen handelt. Wenn man sich entscheiden muss, ob man entweder den gleichen russischen Laut in verschiedenen Namen gleich transkribiert oder den gleichen Personennamen in verschiedenen Büchern gleich transkribiert, würde ich mich klar für letzteres entscheiden und weiter die alte Schreibweise verwenden.

Comment: @quarague: Was hältst du von der Idee, den gleichen russischen Laut in verschiedenen Namen so zu transkribieren, dass er zu einer richtigen Aussprache führt? Bei Горбачёв = Gorbatschow und Хрущёв = Chruschtschow funktioniert das ja auch.

Comment: Die Idee ist wieder die gleiche, eine korrekte Aussprache ist ein wünschenswertes Ziel, eine einheitliche Schreibweise des Names einer konkreten Person auch. Ich würde bei einer historischen Person bei der historischen Schreibweise bleiben, um die Person eindeutig zu identifizieren, auch dann, wenn das eine falsche Aussprache suggeriert. Wenn man ein Wort neu transkribiert, für das es noch keine gebräuchliche Form gibt, sollte man das natürlich nach aktuellen Regeln und Normen tun.

Comment: @quarague: Meiner Wahrnehmung wurden zumindest im aktuellen Jahrhundert deutlich mehr Dokumente mit der Endung *-ow* publiziert als mit *-ef, -eff, -ew* und *-ev* zusammen. In den beiden Jahrhunderten davor mag das anders gewesen sein, aber ich halte nichts davon, an alten Schreibweisen festzuhalten, nur weil es sie mal gegeben hat, während neue und bessere Schreibweisen längst etabliert sind.

Answer (score 3):

Die Frage betrifft scheinbar "nur" die Transkription eines einzelnen russischen Namens ins Deutsche, ist aber eigentlich eine grundsätzliche Frage: Wie sollen Namen von Personen aus dem nicht-deutschen Sprachraum auf Deutsch wiedergegeben werden?

Bei Sprachen, die das lateinische Alphabet verwenden, stellt sich die Frage nur dann, wenn in Namen Sonderzeichen vorkommen, die im Deutschen nicht existieren (diakritische Zeichen und Ligaturen). Meine Meinung ist, dass die Originalschreibweise beibehalten werden sollte, sofern es keine drucktechnischen Hinderungsgründe gibt. Beispielsweise im Vietnamesischen könnte es aufgrund der extrem vielen Diakritika Probleme geben. Die korrekte Wiedergabe setzt im Übrigen gute Kenntnisse des jeweiligen Alphabets voraus. Z.B. hat das Ungarische die Buchstaben  ö und  ő  , die fälschlichweise oft gleichgesetzt werden. So wird etwas der ungarische Mathematiker "Erdős Pál" wird häufig als "Paul Erdös" transkribiert (die *Übersetzung* von Vornamen wäre eine eigene Frage wert).

Bei den Alphabeten von Sprachen wie griechisch, russisch, ukrainisch, bulgarisch, arabisch und hebräisch gibt es Transkriptionstabellen, an denen man sich orientieren sollte.

Im Falle "Чебышёв" wäre die korrekte Transkription m.E. "Tschebyschow". Dennoch gebe ich Jonathan Scholbach Recht:  Die **etablierte** deutsche Transkription ist "Tschebyscheff" und diese sollte auch verwendet werden. Zwar hat Hubert Schölnast zahlreiche jüngere Beispiele der "Tschebyschow"-Variante identfiziert, das ändert aber nichts daran, dass eine hier eine nicht-etablierte Form verwendet wird.

Einer der Knackpunkte ist der russische Buchstabe "ё". Zitat aus [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%81):

> Am 18. Oktober 1783 fand in Sankt Petersburg eine der ersten Sitzungen der Akademie des russischen Schrifttums statt, an der viele führende Literaten und Philologen der damaligen Zeit teilnahmen. Auf dieser Sitzung sprach sich die Präsidentin der Akademie Jekaterina Woronzowa-Daschkowa für die Einführung des Digraphen і᷍о für den entsprechenden Laut aus, was allerdings von kirchlicher Seite als unzulässig abgelehnt wurde. Zum ersten Mal erschien das gedruckte Ё im Jahre 1797 in der zweiten Auflage von Nikolai Karamsins Gedichtssammlung Die Äoniden[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57aqS.jpg). Am 24. Dezember 1942 wurde vom Volkskommissar für Bildung die obligatorische Verwendung des Buchstabens Ё im Schulunterricht angeordnet. Seit 1943 steht Ё als siebter Buchstabe im russischen Alphabet.
> Ё wird vor allem in Druckerzeugnissen durch Е ersetzt, was insbesondere Neulinge der russischen Sprache verwirrt und Unklarheit bei russischen Namen schafft. Mit Ausnahme von Lehr- und Wörterbüchern gilt die Verwendung von Ё in der russischen Schriftsprache bis heute als nicht obligatorisch. Einige Schriftsteller und Verlagshäuser ersetzen es beständig durch Е, andere schreiben es in jedem passenden Wort. Für russische Muttersprachler bereitet die Verwendung von Е anstelle von Ё keine Schwierigkeiten beim Lesen. Im schriftlichen Kontext werden entsprechende Wörter erkannt und automatisch richtig ausgesprochen. Nur in seltenen Fällen ist der Buchstabe Ё zur Verdeutlichung einer richtigen Aussprache erforderlich. Hierbei handelt es sich entweder um Lehnwörter oder um solche russische Wörter, in denen die Abfolge von „е“ und „ё“ bedeutungsunterscheidend ist, z. B.: все (alle) und всё (alles).
> Der Buchstabe Ё und seine Berechtigung zur Existenz ist im Russischen bis heute stark umstritten, wovon einige Artikel in einschlägigen Fachzeitschriften sowie zahlreiche Diskussionsforen im Internet zeugen.

In Anbetracht des hier dargestellten zeitlichen Ablaufs vermute ich, dass die Originalschreibweise seines Namens "Чебышев" ist (sein Geburtsjahr ist 1821) und erst später in "Чебышёв" geändert wurde. Auch russische Quellen scheinen sich nicht einig zu sein:

1. [Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%88%D1%91%D0%B2,_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9B%D1%8C%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) :  Пафну́тий Льво́вич Чебышёв (ошибочн. [= fälschlich] Че́бышев)
2. [booksite.ru](https://www.booksite.ru/fulltext/1/001/008/121/648.htm) : Чебышев (произносится [= ausgespochen] Чебышёв) Пафнутий Львович

Im [Katalog der Deutschen Nationalbibliothek](https://portal.dnb.de/opac.htm?method=simpleSearch&cqlMode=true&query=nid%3D118666118) findet man einen ganzen "Zoo" an Schreibweisen:

> Person    Čebyšev, Pafnutij L.
> Andere Namen
> Tschebischew, P.
> Tschebyschow, P. L.
> Chebyshev, P.L.
> Čebyšev, Pafnutii Lvovič
> Tschebyschef, Pafnutij L'vovič
> Tschebyscheff, Pafnutij Lwowitsch
> Čebyšev, Pafnutij Lʹvovič
> Čebyšev, Pafnutij
> Tchebychef, Pasunti Luvovich
> Tschebychef, Pasunti Luvowitsch
> Tschébyscheff, Pasunti Luvowitsch
> Tschebyscheff, Pafnuti L.
> Čebyšev, Pafnutij L'vovič
> Chebyshev, P. L.
> Tchebychef, P. L.
> Tchébychef, P.
> Tschebychef, P. L.
> Tschebyscheff, P. L.
> Tschebyschew, Pafnuti Lwowitsch
> Tschébyscheff, Pasunti L.
> Tschebyscheff, Pafnutij L.
> Tchebychef, Pasunti L.
> Čebyšev, Pasunti
> Tschebychef, Pasunti L.
> Tschebyschef, P. L.
> Chebyshev, Pafnuty Lvovich
> Tchébichef, Pafnuty Lvovich
> Čebyšev, P. L.
> Tchébychev, P.
> Tschebyschow, Pafnuti L. (RAK-ÖB)
> Tschebyscheff, Pafnuti Levowitsch
> Chebyshev, Pafnutii Lvovich
> Čebyšev, Pafnutij Lvovič
> Tchébychef, Pafnouti Lvovitch

Die obigen Varianten beinhalten auch Transkriptionen ins Englische und Französische. Es wird jedenfalls deutlich, dass das eigentlich korrekte "Tschebyschow" eine äußert selten vorkommende Variante ist.

Zum Abschluss möchte ich Tschebyscheff noch selbst als Autor eines [mathematischen Artikels](https://portal.dnb.de/opac/showFullRecord?currentResultId=auRef%3D118666118%26any&currentPosition=0) "zu Wort" kommen lassen:

[image]

Es wäre ihm ein Leichtes gewesen, die französiche Schreiweise "Tchebychow" zu verwenden. Man sollte auch heute noch seine Entscheidung respektieren.

Comment: Interessant! Ich wusste nicht, dass Tschebyscheff sich quasi selbst übersetzt hat. Allerdings ins Französische. Allerdings wird auch heute noch die Trema über dem russischen e weggelassen. Selbst habe ich das "jo" nur als Hilfskonstrukt kennengelernt, um die richtige Sprechweise zu lernen, aber gerade nicht als Schreibweise. Es ist, wie immer, komplizierter, als ich dachte.

Comment: Da hat Peter S Recht. Und: Das französische E klingt nicht wie das Deutsche, ist ein Bisschen näher dem O. Ob es seine Entscheidung war, so seinen Namen zu buchstabieren ist nur eine Vermutung. (Meinen Namen schreibe ich auch in Artikeln ohne Akzente, weil die Community Namen, die noch fremd klingen, zu vergessen neigt.) Hier wissen wir nicht ob das der Verleger war. Außerdem sind deine Quellen doch einig. Die erste meint, „fälschlich Че́бышев“, d.h. richtig Чебышёв, was die zweite Quelle meint. Sonst stimme ich damit überein, dass der Umlaut auf e der Problemursprung ist.

Comment: @c.p. Der Artikel erschien in: Mémoires présentés à l'Académie Impériale des Sciences de St.-Pétersbourg par divers savants et lus dans ses assemblées, 7.1854, S. 17-33. Es handelt sich also um eine russische Zeitschrift; s. https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Kaiserliche_Akademie_der_Wissenschaften_Sankt_Petersburg#2729555-2. Die Artikel wurdem primär auf französisch veröffentlicht. Egal, ob Tschebyscheff selbst seinen Namen so geschrieben hat oder ein Herausgeber mitgewirkt hat - es war eine von Russen getroffene Entscheidung.

Comment: In englischer Übersetzung des **russischen** Mathematikers Oscar Sheynin liegt  uns das Buch "Definite integrals, the theory of finite differences, the theory of probability" vor.  S. https://portal.dnb.de/opac/showFullRecord?currentResultId=auRef%3D118666118%26any&currentPosition=1. [Dort](https://d-nb.info/972717412/04) wird die Schreibweise "Chebyshev" verwendet.

Comment: Wie gesagt, man bezahlt machmal den Preis, nicht richtig buchstabiert zu werden, um wiedererkannt zu werden. Oder war sein Name zum ersten Mal bei diesen Werken transkribiert? Die russischsprachigen A.D. Egorov, P.I. Sobolevsky, L.A. Yanovich  haben auch *Functional Integrals* geschrieben. Da erscheint auch Chebyshov.  Gleichfalls bei *Chance and Stability* von Vladimir Uchaikin, ‎Vladimir Zolotarev (Thm. 1.9.1), usw.  Es gibt keinerlei Zweifel an der *ё-->o-Regel*, und warum man einen Fehler ausbreiten möchtet, das verstehe ich nicht.

Comment: @c.p. "Zolotarev" ist ein schönes Beispiel: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%91%D0%B2,_%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87. Okay, der Wiki-Artikel bezieht sich nicht auf Vladimir M. Zolotarev (Autor von Chance and Stability), aber der Nachname ist derselbe und hat mit Sicherheit dieselbe Schreibweise.

Comment: Eben, man schreibt laut der von Dir verlinkten Seite auf Deutsch Solotarjow (or Zolotaryov auf Englisch), wenn man weiß, ob der Name des Autors auf Russisch Umlaut hat (Золотарёв), da dann man eindeutig weiß, wie es klingt (ich wusste bloß nicht, dass er Umlaut hat, aber bei Чебышёв wissen wir es, das ist eben der Punkt)

Comment: @c.p. / Paul Frost Verstehe ich nicht. "Золотарёв" sollte doch dann  als "Solotarjow" oder meinetwegen "Zolatarov" trranskribiert werden. In seinem eigenen Buch erscheint er aber in der Schreibweise "Zolotarev". Wo ist hier die Logik?

Comment: Wenn es ganz unbestritten bereits einen ganzen Zoo unterschiedlicher Schreibweisen gibt, warum sollte man dann aus diesem Zoo in einem deutschen Kontext eine Schreibweise wählen, die im Deutschen garantiert eine falsche Aussprache herbeiführt? Wäre es nicht besser, die richtige Aussprache wiederzugeben?

Answer (score 2):

Der [ISO-Standard](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9) definiert eine [Transliteration](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration), also eine buchstabengetreue Übertragung, die ohne Kenntnis der Ausgangsprache und der Transliterationsregeln nicht richtig gelesen werden kann.

Der Duden definiert eine [Transkription](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transkription_(Schreibung)), deren Ziel es ist, auch ohne Kenntnis der Ausgangssprache eine angemessene Aussprache zu ermöglichen. Daher erscheint mir die Transkription *Tschebyschow* als sinnvoller als die Transliteration *Čebyšëv*.*

Letztere kann man in einer Anmerkung oder in Klammern ergänzen, wie es z.B. auch [Wikipedia macht](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pafnuti_Lwowitsch_Tschebyschow); zugleich könnte man darauf hinweisen, dass der Name auch anders, z.B. als *Tschebischew* oder *Tschebischeff*, transkribiert wurde (siehe [DNB](https://d-nb.info/gnd/118666118)).

* <sup>Die Transliteration hat dagegen den Vorteil, dass sie nicht abhängig von der Zielsprache ist. Das dürfte der Grund dafür sein, dass die DNB und mit ihr wahrscheinlich die wissenschaftlichen Bibliotheken ihr den Vorzug geben.</sup>

Comment: Die sprachenunabhängige Transliteration hat aber den Nachteil, dass sie diakritische Zeichen verwendet, die nur in wenigen Sprachen verwendet werden. Den Hatschek (das umgedrehte Dach auf dem C und dem s von Čebyšëv) gibt es nur in einigen slawischen und baltischen Sprachen (Tschechisch, Slowakisch, Lettisch, Litauisch usw.), das Trema (auch in Form von Umlautpunkten) aber in ganz anderen Sprachen (Deutsch, Französisch, Ungarisch, Isländisch, Estnisch, ...) Mit ist keine Sprache bekannt, die beide Zeichen verwendet, und das macht es dann für alle schwer, sie zu verwenden.